# Handling SDL input with a facade

Tags: c++, uml, sdl, sdl-2

Is it possible to handle input with this structure?

[image: Input Facade Diagram]

What I'm trying to do is to create a facade class to handle input from SDL and tell that to the Engine as shown in the diagram. After that the Engine can tell to the mediator that something has to change in a game object.  How would I set this up with C++?

Comment: How would a diagram handle input??

Comment: The structure in the diagram obviously

Comment: Do you use the term mediator as the mediator pattern ? Because I do not understand how your schema is linked to the mediator pattern, see Wikipedia.

Comment: Yes it is the mediator pattern, but I left out the game objects. The mediator communicates between the game objects and the engine.

Comment: so you use a mediator to avoid that the engine knows all details about the game objects ( id game states ?). If I understood correctly, what is the purpose of the façade ? It seems to have nothing to do with the mediator ...

Comment: The purpose of the facade is to simplefy SDL input calls and tell the mediator in a simple way that something has happened.